# Database table doesn't get updated using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I want to update a column in the database, but it doesn't work. I can't understand what the problem could be and I tried a lot of advices from this forum. 
Even though update is called in the log, in the database I can't see any change.

This is the code for updating some records in the table WAGON_LIST:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "vimsaddXaPU")
    private Session s;

    Transaction tx;
    List<WagonList> listAlleGleiseZuAktualisieren = new ArrayList<WagonList>();
    for (String gleis : setKwgZukoGleise) {
        listAlleGleiseZuAktualisieren = (List<WagonList>) s.createCriteria(WagonList.class).add(Restrictions.like("actTrack", gleis + "%")).list();
    }

    String actTrack = null;
    Long actPosition = null;

    // update existent gleises with Gleis
    for (WagonList wagon : listAlleGleiseZuAktualisieren) {

        tx = s.beginTransaction();

        if (wagon != null) {
            actTrack = wagon.getActTrack();
            actPosition = wagon.getActPosition();
            String gleis = null;
            if (actPosition < 10) { 
                gleis = actTrack + "0" + actPosition;
            } else {
                gleis = actTrack + actPosition;
            }

            wagon.setActTrack(gleis);

            ***//Here I tried saveOrUpdate, merge and also without calling, beucase Hibernate sees that in wagon.setActTrack(gleis) above a value is changed and should make the update***
            s.saveOrUpdate(wagon);

            tx.commit();
        }
    }
```

After executing the loop, I tried also with s.flush(), but it didn't help.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="vimsaddXaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/VIMSXaDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation" value="disabled" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="32" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <!--   <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="vimshibernate/SessionFactory"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path"  value="ehcache.xml" /> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

VIMSXaDS is a xa-datasource and contains these:

```
     <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
     <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
```

I am doing the update in a transaction and I can see in the log that the update query is executed

```
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)     update
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)         TFMS.WAGON_LIST 
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)     set
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)         ACT_TRACK=? 
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)     where
[STDOUT] (pool-70-thread-1)         WAGON_ID=?

preparing statement
Dehydrating entity: [hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList#338079199653]
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - KLS30617
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 338079199653
Pre-invalidating space [TFMS.WAGON_LIST]
Executing batch size: 1
success of batch update unknown: 0
about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
closing statement
skipping aggressive-release due to flush cycle
registering flush end
aggressively releasing JDBC connection
releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open      ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
post flush
begin
after transaction begin
commit
automatically flushing session
flushing session
processing flush-time cascades
done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for:    hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for:  hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList
dirty checking collections
Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList.actTrack is dirty
Found dirty properties [[hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList#338079205096]] : [actTrack]
Updating entity: [hs2n.vims.db.entities.WagonList#338079205096]
Processing unreferenced collections
Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 20 objects
Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
```

EDIT: It seems that the database table is updated when a sql procedure is called further in the code and not when flushing or commiting the transaction.
The table is updated with or without using Transaction(the session can handle transactions as well), but the problem is that it's not updated on flush or commit call, but on procedure call.

```
CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ call TFMS.STANDORT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");

    call.setLong(1, p_kwnr);
    call.setString(2, p_gleis);
    call.setLong(3, p_position);
    call.setDate(4, p_eingangsdatum);
    call.setLong(5, p_flag);        
    call.setString(6, p_user);
    call.setLong(7, p_plantID);
    call.registerOutParameter(8, Types.INTEGER);
    call.execute();
```

Comment: Have you tried to move tx = s.beginTransaction(); before   s.saveOrUpdate(wagon); ?

Comment: You're NOT using JPA API. You have a __Session__. That is Hibernate API, not JPA API

Comment: @NeilStockton I would agree with you, but the session is injected using the JPA annotation :/ Apparently Hibernate allows you to cross APIs at your leasure, with unreliable and non-portable code as a result.

Comment: Which still means it is using __Hibernate API__. So what if it steals some standardised stuff, it cannot then claim that it is JPA. EBean steals use of some JPA things, but it isn't the JPA API either

Comment: @NikolayTomitov I tried but isn't working.

Comment: I can be easily wrong, but I would expect the session to handle transactions. Can you try it without manually opening and closing any transactions?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík you're right, the session is handling transactions. I debugged through the code and it seems that the records are not updated after flush() or commit() is triggered , but further in code when a sql procedure is called.  CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ call TFMS.STANDORT_IN_STAMMDATEN_CHECK(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");  call.execute(); Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: So the problem only moved to session, after letting session to handle transactions? Update question pls, comments are not the best place to paste code.